# Анонимные функции PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, замыкания, анонимная-функция

Хочу с помощью анонимной функции проверять какое-то условие, и в случае true, выполнять какой-то код. Для каждого вызова свой. В этом примере main точка входа, например с контроллера или сервиса, не суть.

```
public function main () {
    $this->checkString('Вася Пупкин', function () {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Возвращаю какой-то json'], 200);
    });
}

public function checkString (string $name, callable $callback) {
    if ($name === "Вася Пупкин") {
        return $callback();
    }
}
```

Хочу в любом месте своего сервиса проверять является ли условная строка "Вася Пупкин", если да хочу вызвать каждый раз разный код.

Проблема: `return response()->json(['message' => 'Возвращаю какой-то json'], 200);` никак не срабатывает, пробовал и call_user_func.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понятное дело ничего не будет происходить. Так как `return` возвращает результат анонимной функции и передаёт результат выше, туда где она была вызвана. А дальше вы ничего с результатом не делаете и код просто выполняется дальше.

**Пример.**

```
...
$this->checkString('Вася Пупкин', function () {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Возвращаю какой-то json'], 200);
});

echo 'hello';
```

в результате данного кода выведет на экран `hello`.

А такой вызов:

```
...
return $this->checkString('Вася Пупкин', function () {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Возвращаю какой-то json'], 200);
});

echo 'hello';
```

вернёт результат вашей анонимной функции. Либо редирект либо что-то ещё.

Но функция написана плохо и может иметь несколько разных типов данных. Поэтому надо проверять, например, так:

```
$result = $this->checkString('Вася Пупкин', function () {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Возвращаю какой-то json'], 200);
});
if ($result instanceof RedirectResponse) return $result;

echo $result;
```

В результате либо редирект сделает либо выведет значение на экран если условие не верное.